# django - Query the list of objects and their objects field

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-views

I want to check the `MessageState` of all the `Message` in each `Threads` (i.e. `order_threads_message`), and if any of the Threads has all the messages hidden then make that Thread as hidden too (/ or else remove it from order_threads_message). I want to do that in the view before passing it to the template. How do I do that? If you didn't get me, please ask. I will be happy to explain. Please help me how to do this in the views. I will be grateful. Thank you.

models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class ThreadState(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thread_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()

class MessageState(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    message_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def message(request):
    user = request.user
    threads = user.thread_set.all()
    order_threads_message = threads.annotate(max_sent_date=Max('message__sent_date')).order_by('-max_sent_date')
    if order_threads_message.count() > 0:
        recent_thread = order_threads_message[0]
        if recent_thread.message_set.all().count() > 0:
            recent_thread_conversations = recent_thread.message_set.all()
            return render(request, 'conversations.html', {
                'all_threads':order_threads_message,
                'conversations':recent_thread_conversations,
                'active': recent_thread.id
                })
        else:
            recent_thread_conversations = 0
            return render(request, 'conversations.html', {
                'all_threads':order_threads_message,
                'conversations':recent_thread_conversations,
                'active': recent_thread.id
                })
    else:
        order_threads_message = 0
        recent_thread_conversations = 0
        return render(request, 'conversations.html', {
            'all_threads':order_threads_message,
            'conversations':recent_thread_conversations,
            })
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why MessageState is a separate model from Message, and in particular why you have a ForeignKey relationship - that means there can be multiple MessageStates for each message, which doesn't make sense (what if one state says hidden and one doesn't?)

Comment: Yes, that's the point of it. So that, the message may be hidden for a user who has hide the message, but remain visible to other users who hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran this query for the following models:

**Models**

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class ThreadState(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    thread_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name = 'message_thread')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()

class MessageState(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='messagestate_message')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    message_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Query**

```
Thread.objects.filter(message_thread__in = Message.objects.filter(messagestate_message__in=MessageState.objects.filter(message_hidden=False)))
```

This query will return the `Thread` objects if atleast one of its `MessageState`'s `message_hidden` is `False`.

Comment: I will verify and come back again.

Comment: @ruddra Hi, I am getting an error 
`FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'messagestate_message' into field. Choices ar
e: body, id, messagestate, sender, sender_id, sent_date, thread, thread_id`

Comment: Actually I modified @Kakar 's definition slightly by providing `related_name`, check my answer :) .